# How can I set webgl opacity without losing png transparency?

Tags: webgl, opacity

I use webgl to draw 2d pictures, with two triangles, faster than with canvas 2d context. I keep things very simple, because I only use it to draw pictures, no 3d.
Now I am trying to add opacity to my fragment shader, because webgl context don't have .globalalpha property.

Here is my code :

```
<script id="2d-fragment-shader" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
    precision mediump float;

    uniform sampler2D u_image;
    varying vec2 v_texCoord;
    uniform float alpha;

    void main()
    {
        gl_FragColor = vec4(texture2D(u_image, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t)).rgb, alpha);
    }
</script>

...

webglalpha = gl.getUniformLocation(gl.program, "alpha");

...

gl.uniform1f(webglalpha, d_opacity);
```

d_opacity is the opacity value my drawing function gets as an argument.

The opacity changes, but now my transparent pngs get a black background, though the png transparency used to work before, when I was still using

```
gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t));
```

How can I set opacity without losing the pngs transparency ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to multiply the overriding alpha by the original alpha in the texture:

```
void main()
{
    vec4 color = texture2D(u_image, vec2(v_texCoord.s, v_texCoord.t));
    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb, alpha * color.a);
}
```

For example, when texel A has a PNG opacity of `0.5` and texel B a PNG opacity of `0.3`, you want these to become `0.25` and `0.15` respectively when you set your global alpha to `0.5` and not both `0.5`.

Comment: With this new code I sometimes have a little edge around my sprites. I once had this problem before and I added "premultipliedAlpha:false" in my getContext() call to fix it. The new code seems to ignore it. Whever I remove or let it in the getContext() call, the little edge stays around my sprites. :\ Any idea why ?

Comment: @Diego Could you submit a new question with images displaying the problem?

Comment: I thought it was too related to this question to create another question, but ok I will.